# using CentOS7 yum command not working in root

Tags: bash, centos, yum

I get this when I use yum:

```
$ yum -y update
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So I followed an online answer from here:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/python’: File exists
```

additionally checked for yum:

```
$ type -a yum
yum is /usr/bin/yum
```

and checked python:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

So I am totally confused about what's going on here. This appears to have started possibly after I installed python3 or after I created a new user.

PS. I'm pretty new to Centos7.

update:

```
$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to `python2'

$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Dec  1 11:01 /usr/bin/python -> python2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `file /usr/bin/python` and `ls -l /usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I followed an online answer from here:

From where? There's no actual link. Make sure it's posted so we know who posts such a destructive advice as:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python
```

You should never do such things neither in CentOS nor any other system that uses any kind of packaging (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.).

The only safe thing you can do with files under `/usr/bin` (which are managed by `yum`) is launching them. You should never remove those files manually. If you want to remove things, you should run things like `yum remove <package-name>` which will remove both the binary (if any) and any other supplementary files which belong to the program of the package.

While you haven't screwed up your system completely, you can recreate the proper symlink:

```
ln -fs /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

After this, log out from your SSH/console session then log back in.